# How to change property of the object by event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a constructor:

```
var Constructor = function(property) {
    this.property = property;
    this.changeProperty = function() {
        *by clicking should change the property*
    }
}
```

Then I create an object:

```
var newObject = new Constructor(propertyValue);
newObject.changeProperty();
```

So, is it possible to change the property value of the already created object?

Answer (score 0):

> So, is it possible to change the property value of the already created
>   object?

Yes, try

```
var Constructor = function(property) {
    this.property = property;
    var self = this;
    this.changeProperty = function( newProperty ) {
       self.property = newProperty;
    }
}
```

And invoke it as

```
var newObject = new Constructor(propertyValue);
newObject.changeProperty(newPropertyValue);
```

Comment: Or just: `newObject.property = newPropertyValue;` ;)

Comment: Thanks, according to console.log() the value is changed, but the result on the screen is the same.. I mean this pattern is used on slider, and the value which needs to be changed is "autoplay" property. So, the console.log() gives an updated one, however the autoplay is still working..

Answer (score 0):

```
var Constructor = function(property) {
    this.property = property;
    this.changeProperty = function(newProp) {
        this.property = newProp
    }
}

var newObject = new Constructor("oldProp");

newObject.property //oldPropery
newObject.property = "newproperty" 
newObject.property//"newproperty"
```

You can also do it using [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).The property is already public.